# Does jQuery or browser update an element if content is the same?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I return a dictionary to a Ajax call and update items according to it:

```
 if (data.hasOwnProperty("items")) {
       $.each(data.items, function(key, value){
             $("#" + key).html(value);
       });
 }
```

Some of the items could have the same content I want to pass to `html(value)`. Should I check this before changing the HTML or is it checked in jQuery or browser itself before updating them?

I ask it for performance and possible flickering issues, otherwise if the browser somehow handle them I can ignore this.

Comment: jquery doesn't check, it just does what you tell it to. Whether or not you should check first depends on the content.

Comment: jQuery doesn't check; you should incorporate checking logic. Try something like this `setInterval(() => $("#myDiv").html("test"), 1000);` and watch the node in Developer Tools -- you'll notice it flashing every 1s.

Comment: @KevinB I ask it for performance and possible flickering issues, otherwise if the browser somehow handle them I can ignore this. It's a valid question because I think a system can check if there is no need for update it can ignore it for many reasons such as flickering.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you may want to compare them... which will depend on what exactly the content is, whether or not it can contain html entities, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I check this before changing the HTML

Yes

> or is it checked in jQuery

No

> or browser itself before updating them?

No, the browser doesn't prevent value replacement even if the existing value is the same.
You can verify that behaviour by trying something like this:

```
setInterval(() => $("#myDiv").html("test"), 1000);
```

Watch the node in Developer Tools -- you'll notice it flashing every 1s.

Answer (score 0):

You could test each element individually. It's a trade off. This is less performant than just updating all elements since it involves extra operations. However if flickering is a concern, this might remedy that.

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("items")) {
   $.each(data.items, function(key, value){
      if ($(`#${key}`).html().trim() !== value.trim()) $(`#${key}`).html(value);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks I clarified my question, it's not about being empty, but havign the same value.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not empty, its contents will be replaced.

However, jQuery does check in as much as if the element is not empty, it uses `jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );` so that any bound event handlers and data are removed.

See [the source (as of 2021-07-16)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0f623fdc8db128657716290cb7d57430e224c977/src/manipulation.js#L389) for more information on exact implementation.

Comment: I believe the OP's question is about `.html(value)` replacing the value even if the value in in the DOM is already the same as the one in the function argument.

Comment: And the source code is for the `html()` function... As I said, the contents will be replaced. jQuery **will** check to see if there are contents and if so, clear the events and data. You can verify that in the source code I've linked to. The first sentence answers the question. The second goes into more detail. The third provides a link to the source code as proof of what was said in the preceding sentences.